# VHDL range assignment

Tags: range, vhdl

Can someone please explain me the difference between:

```
grant_o(1 downto 1) <= grant_s(1);
```

and

```
grant_o(1) <= grant_s(1);
```

The first one doesn't go through the synthesis tool.

Comment: In the first signal assignment statement the target is a slice name (a one dimensional array) and the right hand expression is an indexed name which denotes an element of the named object. The type of the target array is the type of the named object. The type of the right hand expression is the type of the element of the named object. The type of the expression and the type of the target are not the same.

Comment: Although in this case the problem is obvious, it's generally better to report what you mean by "doesn't go through" ... such as the actual error message, and whether or not it worked in simulation first. This problem should have been caught when you simulated...

Comment: Thank you guys! Its clear what you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `mySignal(index)` accesses a single element of an array. So the value of the expression  is of the element type.

The syntax `mySignal(index1 downto index2)` accesses a range of elements in an array. So the value of the expression is of the same array type, but with a changed range constraint.

Your first example would work if you use `grant_o(1 downto 1) <= grant_s(1 downto 1);`.

Or

`grant_o(1 downto 1) <= (others => grant_s(1));`

Both variants create an array on the right side so it can be assigned to the left side. Your example uses a range of length one.